# Permission denied when django writes to external device

Tags: python, django, apache2, file-permissions

I have a django file server. The server works perfectly on my laptop & localhost (with external hard drive) but when I transferred it to my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, it starts acting up.

I did a lot of googling and tried every possible solution but it does not work. 
Here is my problem:

I have connected an external hard drive to my raspberry pi. I believe it has write permissions because I can easily write to it with mkdir. I have also set this directory which is /media/pi/SAMSUNG/media as my MEDIA_ROOT.

Now I have set up Apache2, WSGI and Django, everything works, I have set up all the permissions and everything, but still when django tries to access the hard drive, whether it be to read or write, I get an error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/pi/SAMSUNG'.

I have fixed this in the past with chown -R 777 but it does not work this time.

Unfortunetly, I have no idea what I am doing when it comes to servers and file permissions, so I have no idea what code to attach. Can some please help me?

I will attach all the necessary code on request.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On raspbian you have to be careful when using external drives. Have you edited the file **/etc/fstab**? This is necessary to mount the drive also correctly after restarts and when the file is temporarily disconnected and then connected again.
If you did this correctly, then the drive will have the permissions you gave it when mounting and Django should be able to access it/write to it.

BR

Comment: BR no I haven't. I read it once but didn't think it was necessary since raspbian auto mounts. What would I edit in fstab to help me?

Comment: For infos `man fstab`. A sample edit could be `'UUID=3C34-8766 /media/pi exfat defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0'`. The value of UUID can be found by `blkid` and then look for your drive. At least I had to edit the fstab.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try that then come back with the results. I believe you may be right becuase I also get the "Operation not permitted" error and when researched about it, I came across fstab. So I wi definitely try your solution.

Comment: This is used to mount the drive permanently in the filesystem. The auto mount is probably just udev. In general you can also check the permissions of files/dirs using  `ls -l`. but you probably know that anyway.  And to change `sudo chmod ...`.Which in this case will change permissions until the next time the pi is rebooted or the drive is detached and attached again.